# Html 5 custom attribute select using jquery if it has multiple values

Tags: jquery, html

In html you can apply multiple css classes to a object e.g `class="a b c"`. In jquery its nice and handy to work with all elements with these classes e.g.

```
jQuery('.b').hide();
```

In Html 5 using custom attributes, jQuery seems to recognise multiple values e.g. `dataset="a b c"` as abc i.e. selectable through:

```
jQuery('tr[dataset="a b c"]').hide();
```

but

```
jQuery('tr[dataset="a"]').hide();
```

does not select any elements with `dataset="a b c"`

Obviously i can think of two/three work arounds but is there a way for jQuery to recognise multiple values in a custom attr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [Attribute Contains Word Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/) will do what you are looking for:
`jQuery('tr[dataset~="a"]').hide();`

Update: Here is a simple [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1omd1u4m/)

Comment: For more up-votes, add a jsfiddle, pen, or code snippet.

Comment: nice and simple one :)